# Is it possible to print a trace message when an expression is fully evaluated?

Tags: haskell

In haskell, one can print a trace message at the *beginning* time of the evaluation for an expression, using `trace`-family:

```
let myExpr = trace "myExpr!" . my . super . complicated $ expr
```

However, I have yet to find a way to print such message at the *end* of the evaluation, that is, the time when this myExpr no longer needs any further evaluation.

Is it possible to do? Or does it even make sense? This could come in handy in many scenarios. For example, I want to see when -- if ever -- an expensive list is fully evaluated.

Another example is when I use the `parallel` package, I want to trace the end of each thread:

```
[expr1, expr2, ..., expr10] `using` parlist rdeepseq
```

I want to print debug information like:

```
expr1 started ...
expr2 started ...
...
expr10 started ...
expr1 finished ...
expr2 finished ...
...
expr10 finished ...
```

Comment: Perhaps something like ``let x = .... in x `deepseq` trace "done!"``?

Comment: @Eric: Yeah I guess it would work. For my second example one may do `let x = ... in trace "start!" x \`deepseq\` trace "done!" x`